# How to set menu active link background

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to set active link background to some color even while moved to clicked URL.
I have tried this but it is changing background but while it navigate to clicked URL all things set to default.

I am trying to add **active** class to clicked menu using JQuery. Code is like this.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">COMPANY PROFILE</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">ENQUIRY</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu-item a{
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFF;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 7px 15px;
line-height: 43px;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #555;
}
.menu-item a:hover{
background: #871304;
opacity: 0.8;
border-radius: 20px;
}
.menu-item .active{
background-color:#FFF;
color:black;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".menu-item a").click(function(){
    $(".menu-item a").addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
```

Please let me know that where I am making mistake?

Comment: Do it in the HTML of the page you are linking to.

Comment: If you are changing your HTML then you need a way to store the value or read in wich page you are to identify the active link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is good except your jQuery. What you want is to remove any `active` class applied to any `menu-item a` element before you apply an `active` to a new element. Check the jQuery part below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".menu-item a").click(function() {
    $(".menu-item a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 7px 15px;
  line-height: 43px;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #555;
}
.menu-item a:hover {
  background: #871304;
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.menu-item .active {
  background-color: #871304;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">COMPANY PROFILE</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">ENQUIRY</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually going to be linking to different pages, then you need to highlight the menu item for the page that you are on. But it seems like you are probably building a single-page site using a jQuery DOM.

If you just want this to work on a single page, you need to change your JS code. What you have right now is basically saying this:

- When a menu item is clicked...
- Select all menu items
- Add class "active" to them
- Select all the siblings for each menu item (which effectively does nothing)
- Remove class "active" from them

So this is clearly not what you want . To operate on just the item that was clicked, use the `$(this)` selector, like so:

```
$(".menu-item a").click(function(){  // When a menu item is clicked
    $(".menu-item a").removeClass('active'); // Select all menu items and remove active class
    $(this).addClass('active');              // Add active class to THIS menu item (that was clicked)
});
```

Comment: I got this what you say here. But I need to highlight that link even when reached to new page which was clicked previously.

Comment: In that case you can just change the background in the HTML for each page. But if you need to do it programatically, [maybe this link will help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919406/highlighting-current-page-item-in-the-nav-menu-with-jquery)